# kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i am trying to code my app in **kotlin** but i am getting `null cannot be casted to non-null type` and it **force my app to close**. i tried to reference to other stackoverflow where they shift the init but i do not have any init portion in my current code. any help will be appreciated thank you.

**reminder_fragment.kt**

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_fragment, container, false)

        //getting recyclerview from xml
        val recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.reminderrecycler) as RecyclerView

        //adding a layoutmanager
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ,false)

        //crating an arraylist to store users using the data class user
        val reminderlist = ArrayList<reminders>()

        //adding some dummy data to the list
        reminderlist.add(reminders("Belal Khan"))
        reminderlist.add(reminders("Ramiz Khan"))
        reminderlist.add(reminders("Faiz Khan"))
        reminderlist.add(reminders("Yashar Khan"))

        //creating our adapter
        val adapter = CustomAdapter(reminderlist)

        //now adding the adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        return v;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val manager = supportFragmentManager

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_reminders -> {
                createReminderFragment()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        bottom_navigation.setItemIconTintList(null);
        createReminderFragment()
        bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }

    /*private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentplaceholder, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }*/

    fun createReminderFragment() {
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        val fragment = reminder_fragment()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentplaceholder, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }


}
```

**reminder_fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".reminder_fragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/reminderrecycler"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomAdapter.kt**

```
class CustomAdapter(val reminderlist: ArrayList<reminders>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.reminder_fragment, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v);
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return reminderlist.size    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(reminderlist[position])
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItems(reminders: reminders) {
            val medicineText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.medicineText) as TextView
            medicineText.text = reminders.medicineN

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: share your crash logcat.

Comment: You can just use `v.reminderrecycler` instead of `findViewById(...) as RecyclerView`. You can also set the LayoutManager in XML with `app:layoutManager` and `android:orientation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You does not implement your **RecyclerView**  well.
You must have an seperated layout for RecyclerView items .
You set your RecyclerView items layout , your layout which your RecylerView decalared in it now .

**Therefor** android can not find your TextView with Id medicineText

**I recommend you to do these:**

1) Create a seperate layout for your RecyclerView items and inflate it to your holder as below :

```
val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recylerView_item, parent, false)
```

2) put in an TextView in RecylerView item  layout with id of medicineText

3)Use ? symbol to handle possible NullPonterException when you declaring your TextView

```
    val medicineText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.medicineText) as? TextView
```

Comment: ill give it a try thanks! ill update you on the outcome :)

Comment: Hi Sorry for the long wait! @alireza-bideli, it finally works :) you're a lifesaver!